# SMPlayer Bookmarks Backup:

Tags: 16.04, backup, smplayer

Is there anyway to take backup of SMPlayer bookmarks, otherwise what is the bookmark path in the Ubuntu 16.04 of SMPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

The 'Bookmarks', perhaps more correctly known as 'Favorites' in Xenial's SMPlayer version 15.11.0, are stored in the following path:

```
~/.config/smplayer/favorites.m3u8
```

This *single file* can be easily backed up to the media of your choice. For example on my own setup I backup to an external USB drive:

```
andrew@ilium~$ cp -v ~/.config/smplayer/favorites.m3u8 /run/media/andrew/CORSAIR/
'/home/andrew/.config/smplayer/favorites.m3u8' -> '/run/media/andrew/CORSAIR/favorites.m3u8'
andrew@ilium~$
```

Easy :)